# Primefaces monitorDownload fires stop right after start function

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm facing an using with Primefaces monitorDownload (PF 3.4.2).

I would like to create a file and download it with a commandButton. Clicking the button, the stop function is fired right after the start function. Then the generation + download request is properly done. So the end function is not fired at the end of the download but at the begin, same moment as the start function.

Not really what I want. I would like this scenario :

- Click the button
- Loading spinning wheel appears (showing the generation is in progress)
- Generation of the file
- Loading spinning disappears
- File download request by the browser

There my code :

```
<h:form>
 <pf:panel>
  <pf:commandButton value="Export database" id="exportDatabase" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(window.alert('start'), window.alert('stop'));">
    <pf:fileDownload value="#{bean.exportDatabase()}" />
  </pf:commandButton>
 </pf:panel>
</h:form>
```

The bean side :

```
private StreamedContent exportDatabaseFile;

public StreamedContent exportDatabase() {

        String exportDatabaseFilename = "nameOfTheFile.xlsx";
        Path nameExportDatabasePath = "C:\nameOfTheFile.xlsx";                               

        // Populate exportDatabaseFile    
        exportDatabaseFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(nameExportDatabasePath.toFile()), FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getMimeType(exportDatabaseFilename), exportDatabaseFilename);    
        return exportDatabaseFile;
}
```

Any idea of how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

private StreamedContent exportDatabaseFile;

```
public StreamedContent exportDatabase() {

        String exportDatabaseFilename = "nameOfTheFile.xlsx";
        Path nameExportDatabasePath = "C:\nameOfTheFile.xlsx";                               

        // Populate exportDatabaseFile    
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(nameExportDatabasePath.toFile()), FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getMimeType(exportDatabaseFilename), exportDatabaseFilename);            
}
```